# Cloudinary URL doesn't create Cloud url, via SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, cloudinary

So in my:

`application.css.scss` file I have the following line:

```
background-image: cloudinary-url('billie-piper-reading-book', $width: '100%');
```

In development environment it loads with this asset pipeline:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/billie-piper-reading-book
```

Which results in:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/billie-piper-reading-book 404 (Not Found)
```

I would assume, that `cloudinary-url` should genereate something like `http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/billie-piper-reading-book`...

Any reason?

Any support will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate a Cloudinary URL for a static image, you should first run a rake task and follow up the steps as explained in the following blog:
http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_deliver_your_static_images_through_a_cdn_in_ruby_on_rails

After the image is synced with your Cloudinary account, the following code example should work:

```
background-image: cloudinary-url('billie-piper-reading-book.jpg');
```

This will generate a URL like the following (mind the `asset` type):

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<your_cloud_name>/image/asset/billie-piper-reading-book.jpg
```

If you want to use an already uploaded image, you can also set the `type` parameter to `upload`:

```
background-image: cloudinary-url('billie-piper-reading-book.jpg', $type: 'upload');
```

to generate a URL like (mind the `upload` type):

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<your_cloud_name>/image/upload/billie-piper-reading-book.jpg
```

Also note that `$width: '100%'` isn't accepted in [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp). You might want to consider using [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) instead.

Comment: Can I ask, if you wanted to scale the `background-image` for different size screens, is this still resized by Cloudinary? It seems like if we toggled `background-size` then the resizing happens on the client side, and the same full size image is downloaded, which would reduce one of the key benefits of Cloudinary.

Answer (score 1):

If you need HTTPS like me, use :

```
background-image: cloudinary-url('billie-piper-reading-book.jpg', $secure: true);
```